# "Yearly" or "every year" in a sentence

Tags: word-choice

Given Sentence:

> She paid the interest on the pawn ticket every year.

Can I change the word *every year* to *yearly* in the above sentence?

> She paid the interest on the pawn ticket yearly.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you're trying to emphasise. If you're emphasising that she always paid the interest on the ticket, then use "every year". If you want to emphasise that the interest comes due on an annual basis, then use "yearly". The two are somewhat interchangeable, and people will understand either one, but ideally you would use "every X" to emphasise not missing a payment.

Another option would be "once a year", which is kind of a middle ground.

Comment: ... or *annually*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the word yearly as an adverb or every year as an adverbial phrase, without any difference in meaning.  Per The Free Dictionary, yearly means every year; without missing a year.

However, when you are talking about an amount of money received or paid, the more appropriate and common word is annually.

She pays interest on the pawn ticket annually.